# Error in PHP when function is called from java script

Tags: javascript, php

```
$func=$_GET['func']?$_GET['func']:$_POST['func'];
```

While calling this function 
following error is showing

```
Notice: Undefined index: func in C:\wamp\www\Web Engg final project\phplogin.php on line 2
```

this error us showing ?

Comment: [Undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770836#12770836). You're trying to make reference to `$_GET['func']` when it's not available. On page load both `$_GET['func']` and `$_POST['func']` are not available, you will need to check to see if they exist before using as setters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you are not getting `$_GET['func']` also `$_POST['func']`.

You are assuming that if `$_GET['func']` is not set, there will be `$_POST['func']`.

**Instead of it, add a logic:**

1) Create a new variable `$func`, default it to blank.

2) If isset($_GET['func']), assign to it.

3) If isset($_POST['func']), assign to it.

**Code:**

```
$func = '';
if (isset($_GET['func'])) {
 $func = $_GET['func'];
}
else if (isset($_POST['func'])) {
 $func = $_POST['func'];
}
```